IVP equal to integral equation
I have just recently started getting into differential equations and their solutions. Now I have discovered this theorem:
Let $m \in \mathbb{N}, I=[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}, f: I \times \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^m$ continuous and $y \in C^0(I)^m$.
$y$ is in $C^1(I)^m$ and it is a solution to the initial value problem $y'(x)=f(x,y(x)), y(a)=y_0$ if and only if $y(x)=y_0+\int_a^x f(s, y(s)) ds$.
I get what the theorem is saying but I don't completely understand why that would be true. I've been trying to prove it but don't seem to be able to do so correctly.
I think I've been able to prove the first direction $"\Rightarrow"$ but I struggle to do the second one. How can I show that if $y$ is the solution to the integral equation, it is also continuously differentiable? Am I overlooking something obvious? If I know that $y$ has this property I think it is easy to prove that $y'(x) = f(x, y(x))$ (because then you can simply differentiate $y$ and get the desired equation).

Define $g$ given by $g(x)=f(x,y(x))$. This is a continuous function as $f$ and $y$ are continuous. The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus tells us that $G$ given by $G(x)=\displaystyle\int_a^x f(s, y(s)) \,ds$ is an antiderivative of $g$.
As $G'=g$ and $g$ is continuous, $G$ is continuously differentiable, which implies that $y$ is $\mathcal{C}^1$ too. As you mentioned, by differentiating we immediately get $y'(x)=g(x)=f(x,y(x))$.

Sometimes I'm so dumb. Thank you very much!
